# convert string to values

Tags: python, pandas, string, mysql-connector

First of all I am not sure how correct my question is.

I want to upload data to MySQL database.

```
columns3=[]
for i in df.columns:
    i="row."+str(i)
    columns3.append(i)
for row in df.itertuples():
    mycursor.execute(insert into df2(rk, age, g, gs, mp, fg, fga) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s),(columns3))
mydb.commit()
```

output for columns3 is this:

```
['row.rk',
 'row.age',
 'row.g',
 'row.gs',
 'row.mp',
 'row.fg',
 'row.fga']
```

data is of string type, so it is imported to MySQL database like this:
[image]

columns3 should be row.rk, row.age,row.age and etc. (without quotes).

How can I convert these str values to desired values

Comment: what is your desired value

Comment: I want to conver 'row.rk', 'row.age', 'row.g' to row.rk, row.age, row.g (to remove quotes)

Comment: What type of data is `row.rk` if it is not a string?

Comment: type(row.rk)  is float (in dataframe column "rk" is of type float. type('row.rk') is str

Comment: So you want to insert the value of `row.rk` into the SQL database?

Comment: yes.  I want to insert it as row.rk (not as "row.rk")

Comment: I think `row['rk']` is what you want to retrieve the value of the column from the pandas df. Can you try that?

Comment: yes. That is what I want to get. I will try it

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a pandas DataFrame `df` with some columns:

```
cols = tuple(df.columns)
num_cols = len(cols)
statement = "INSERT INTO df2 (" + ", ".join(cols) + ") VALUES (" + ", ".join("%s" for _ in range(num_cols)) + ")" 
for row in df.itertuples():
    mycursor.execute(statement, row[-num_cols:])
mydb.commit()
```

The `row` is returned as a `tuple` with `index/indices` followed by `column` values. I'm slicing the last `num_cols` values from the tuple to get the column values to pass to the SQL database.

This should give you the desired results.